# Using Split and Replace - VBA

Tags: vba, replace, split

I'm facing a strange problem in VBA.
I'm trying to write a macro that will replace the comma by a dot.

My conditions are:

- if the first comma is followed by another comma, then Replace the 2nd comma by a dot
- Else, replace the 3rd comma by a dot

So the input/output should look like that:

```
INPUT           OUTPUT
1,,3,4          1,.3,4
1,2,3,4         1,2,3.4
1,,3,4          1,.3,4
1,2,3,4         1,2,3.4
```

My macro looks like that:

```
Sub replaceComma()
For i = 1 To 3
   
    If Left(Split(ActiveSheet.Range("A" & i), ",")(1), 1) = "" Then
        ActiveSheet.Range("A" & i) = Replace(ActiveSheet.Range("A" & i), "," & Split(ActiveSheet.Range("A" & i), ",")(2), "." & Split(ActiveSheet.Range("A2"), ",")(2))
    ElseIf Left(Split(ActiveSheet.Range("A" & i), ",")(1), 1) <> "" Then
        ActiveSheet.Range("A" & i) = Replace(ActiveSheet.Range("A" & i), "," & Split(ActiveSheet.Range("A" & i), ",")(3), "." & Split(ActiveSheet.Range("A2"), ",")(3))

    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

But the OUTPUT I get is this:

```
1,.3,4
1,2,3.4
1,.3.4,4
1,2,3,4
```

So the macro is working great for the first and second row, but it doesn't work for all the other rows.
I notice that the 3rd row is using the 2nd row but I don't get why
Moreover, if I try to increment i to 4, I get an error " 9- Out of range".

Thanks in advance for your help.
Alex

Comment: You have some static `Split(ActiveSheet.Range("A2"), ",")(2))` at the end instead of `"A" & i`

Comment: OH that's right, I'm sorry
Thank you !

Comment: I corrected it but I still have a problem.
Do you know why this macro replaces 2 commas instead of one when there's 1,,2,2,3 for example ? I get 1,.2.2,3 instead of 1,.2,2,3

Comment: I think that the split functions returns just the field between two commas, is there a way two split the cell to get all the remaining string after the comma ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution that might be simpler could be to look for double comma ",," , and then use the excel substitute function to replace either the second or the third occurrence of comma.

```
Sub replaceComma(r As Range)
    Dim c As Range
    For Each c In r.Cells
        If InStr(c.Value2, ",,") = InStr(c.Value2, ",") Then
            c.Value2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(c.Value2, ",", ".", 2)
        Else
            c.Value2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(c.Value2, ",", ".", 3)
        End If
    Next c
    
End Sub
```

PS: I changed the function to use a range as argument, but you can modify it to use your loop instead.

PPS: Modified according to LS_dev suggestion

Comment: Much cleaner than mine, loL!

Comment: Thank you, this looks very nice !!
But being a beginner, can you explain me how do you pass a range in a sub ? 
The range I will always use for this macro is A:A (all the rows of A)

Comment: Anyways, your solution work perfectly fine, thank you so much

Comment: How do you check if there's a double comma before a certain amount of commas ? Because in my data, I will always have double commas at some point, it's just the beginning that needs to be touched

Comment: Yep, double commas not in first place will break this function. Must use something like `InStr(c.Value2, ",,")=InStr(c.Value2, ",")` in condition.

Comment: Yes that's a good thing, but now my final problem is that my double comma in the data is not the first comma in the cell, it's right in the middle... is it possible to do a condition like this  If Instr(c.Value2, ",,")= "Position of the 6th comma" ??

Comment: So your real conditions are not the ones given in the question. Could you Update it?

Answer (score 0):

A bit of a work-around, but you could use something like this:

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub replaceComma()
    
    Dim r As Long
    Dim split_array As Variant
    
    For r = 1 To 4
   
        split_array = Split(Range("A" & r).Value, ",")
        
        'check if first comma followed by second comma
        'i.e. split(1) will be empty
        If split_array(1) = "" Then
            Range("A" & r).Value = split_array(0) & ",." & split_array(2) & "," & split_array(3)
        Else
            Range("A" & r).Value = split_array(0) & "," & split_array(1) & "," & split_array(2) & "." & split_array(3)
        End If
    
    Next r
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Just because I like formulas when I can avoid VBA, I would suggest formula:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1;",";".";IFERROR(FIND(",,";A1)*0+2;3))
```

which would work for given samples, but would render `1,2,,4` as `1,2.,4`, and that would violate given rules.

So, instead I have to suggest:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1;",";".";IF(FIND(",";A1;FIND(",";A1)+1)=FIND(",";A1)+1;2;3))
```

or, using boolean arithmetic:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1;",";".";3-(FIND(",";A1;FIND(",";A1)+1)=FIND(",";A1)+1))
```

And that would work for any sample with three commas:

```
Input     Output
1,2,3,4   1,2,3.4
1,2,3,    1,2,3.
1,2,,4    1,2,.4
1,2,,     1,2,.
1,,3,4    1,.3,4
1,,3,     1,.3,
1,,,4     1,.,4
1,,,      1,.,
,2,3,4    ,2,3.4
,2,3,     ,2,3.
,2,,4     ,2,.4
,2,,      ,2,.
,,3,4     ,.3,4
,,3,      ,.3,
,,,4      ,.,4
,,,       ,.,
```